# how to make an association two-ways street in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables, `users` and `profiles`. `users has_one profile`, `profiles belongs_to user`.

I can `@profiles.user.email` to access `email` column in users table. However, I cannot `@users.profile.lastname` to access `lastname` column in `profile` table. It seems it has only one-street and going upward.

How can I make this two-ways street and going downward as well?

Answer (score 0):

A has_one-belongs_to relationship should be a two way street already.

Make sure you have:

**User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :profile
end
```

**Profile model**

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end
```

If you have both of those set up correctly then add some code to your answer so people might be able to see where the problem is.

**UPDATE**

You could use the rails console to test if the association works correctly. Use `rails c -s` in the terminal to open the rails console in sandbox mode (all your changes will be rolled back when you finish).

In the console create a user and a profile then check if it works how it should.

```
user = User.create!(email: 'example@email.com')
user.create_profile!(last_name: 'test')
```

Then try `user.profile.last_name` and see what you get!

Comment: This is exactly what I have.

Comment: <table border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User Email</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Last login Time</th>
       
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td><%= user.profile.lastname %></td>
          <td><%= user.last_sign_in_at %></td>
          <td><%= user.admin %></td>

          <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
          
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

Comment: undefined method `lastname' for nil:NilClass

Comment: if i delete <%= user.profile.lastname %>, the rest of them would work. I have changed primary key to user_id in profiles table. I wonder if this is where the problem come from.

Comment: Did you change the primary key or the foreign key to `user_id`? The foreign key should be `user_id` so that shouldn't cause the problem.

Are you sure that the users profile exists in the database? You should be able to test if the association is working using the rails console. I have updated my answer above with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a brand new application to test the association. Yes, they are two ways street.

Something must went wrong when I had changed the primary key to be user_id in profile table...

Sorry, I asked this question too prematurely.